# Error while inserting a value from loop into a new column

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to insert the loop value as a new column in the main data.frame . The error I get is it inserts only the first time and the rest of the values in the same loop is blank.

```
data <- data.frame()
for(k in 1:length(data$emp.Code)) {
  
  res = GET(paste0("https://urlpart1",data$emp.Code[[k]],"&StartDate=01-01-2023&EndDate=02-28-2023"))

  tmp = fromJSON(rawToChar(res$content))
  tmp$emp_code <- data$emp.Code[[k]] ### this is the code to insert the loop value as new column
  data <- rbind(data, as.data.frame(tmp))
  }
```

Comment: If you run `data <- data.frame()` then `length(data)` you will see the issue others have indicated. To run a loop with an unknown number of iterations, use `while()`. Without an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I can't say how to define your `while()`. But there are other issues with you loop. You call data$emp.Code[[k]] in your `paste0()` statement but neither emp.Code or data[[k]] exist. I looks like you want data$emp.Code[[k]] to be an integer, so just use k if this is the case. Using a `break` in an `if()` that's nested in a `for()` might also work.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, `data` is an empty dataframe. In `1:length(data$emp.Code)` there is no such thing as `emp.Code` in your data, so the loop probably goes 1:0, returning only the 1st column. Can you use something other to indicate how many times the loop should repeat?

Comment: example for each api call based on employee code it may create 50 records or 100 records. so its not consistent in terns of how many times the loop should repeat

Comment: The for loop depends on the number of records, so you should find that out before calling the for loop.

Comment: will that be a loop inside a loop

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `purrr` helps

```
library(purrr)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
employee_code <- c(1:2)
map_dfr(employee_code, function(x){
  res = GET(paste0("https://urlpart1", x ,"&StartDate=01-01-2023&EndDate=02-28-2023"))
  tmp = fromJSON(rawToChar(res$content)) |> 
    dplyr::mutate(emp_code = x)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Start your object as NULL

```
data <- NULL
```

Option 2: Save your iteration result as data.frame inside a list slot, and then bind them together. If not all the columns are same, you can solve it

```
data <- list() # Empty list for saving results
for(k in 1:length(data$emp.Code)) {
  
  res = GET(paste0("https://urlpart1",data$emp.Code[[k]],"&StartDate=01-01-2023&EndDate=02-28-2023"))

  tmp = fromJSON(rawToChar(res$content))
  tmp$emp_code <- data$emp.Code[[k]] ### this is the code to insert the loop value as new column
 data[[k]] <- data
  }

final_data <- do.call(plyr::rbind.fill, data) ## Convert to data.frame filling columns
head(final_data)
```